# Header files won't work in C

Tags: c, mingw, header-files

I'm using Dev-CPP, (but programming in C), and the header files won't work. I've gone to compiler option; directories; c inludes and checked the directory is correct, and it is. The include files are stored in C:\Dev-Cpp\include and that's where it's set to receive them.

For example:

```
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  textcolor(1);

  printf("Why won't header files work? \n");

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried with several other header files, but they also don't work. I'm sure the answer is really obvious, but I'm clearly too stupid to fix this. I'm also using MinGW as the compiler, (comes standard with dev-cpp). Please help me.

Comment: Does it also fail with `stdlib.h`?

Comment: Please define `won't work`. Does the compiler complain, that the header does not exist or is there some other error message? If so please add it to your question. Also `stdlib.h` should be included, because you use `system`.

Comment: I get an error saying "undefined reference to textcolor". If I place a number in the parentheses; but if, for example, I write RED in the parentheses I get the error 'RED' undeclared.

Comment: @user3276467 This is why you should always post the error messages. Your problem is unrelated to header files. You actual have a linking error, you need to specify to the linker the path to the object file including the implementation of textcolor. But I don't know which file this is in Windows. Please edit your question and add the error message.

Comment: Sorry; It is because I'm not using Borland/Turbo C. Issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textcolor() very old.(Perhaps borland c++ ?)

e.g. redefine like this

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void textcolor(unsigned short color){
    HANDLE hStdout;
    WORD wAttributes;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbi);

    wAttributes = color ;
    if (color & 0x08) wAttributes |= FOREGROUND_INTENSITY ;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, wAttributes);
}

/*
#define FOREGROUND_BLUE      0x0001
#define FOREGROUND_GREEN     0x0002
#define FOREGROUND_RED       0x0004
#define FOREGROUND_INTENSITY 0x0008

#define BACKGROUND_BLUE      0x0010
#define BACKGROUND_GREEN     0x0020
#define BACKGROUND_RED       0x0040
#define BACKGROUND_INTENSITY 0x0080
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    textcolor(1);
//  textcolor(FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    printf("FOREGROUND_BLUE \n");

    textcolor(4);
    printf("FOREGROUND_RED \n");

    textcolor(7);
    system("PAUSE");  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's because conio.h is Borland. I've found ways around not using it so I'm fine now. Thanks though! Sorry for being an idiot!

Answer (score 2):

conio.h header file doesn't work with dev cpp because it is not part of c standard.
http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/faq.html

Comment: Just tried it in CodeLite - same issue... unless CodeLite also doesn't support conio.h

Comment: conio.h is windows specific. which os are u using?

Comment: Windows (7). dos.h also doesn't work.