# Search txt file then print at console txt file and colour the string which search

Tags: c, search, colors, console

I made a program which searches for a string, here is code: [When we search word in txt file how we could colour in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945310/when-we-search-word-in-txt-file-how-we-could-colour-in-txt-file)
I want to print at console all text with underline string. How can I do this?
I am using linux

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your terminal is capable of. Check your `terminfo`, and see (for instance) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html for some coding variants (that page calls it 'underscored').

For me, on Mac OSX's Terminal, printing the following escape code works:

```
"\x1b[4m"
```

-- defined as `PP_UNDERLINE`, I can use it like this:

```
printf ("processing file " PP_UNDERLINE "%s" PP_RESET, argv[i]);
```

to get underlined text in my terminal output:

[image: sample of underlined output]

Comment: i know how i can uderline terminal but i do not know how i can uderline namely the word which i search in the ttxt

Comment: Please type a bit slower ;) To underline just a single word, 1. make sure underline is OFF; 2. print text up to that word; 3. switch underline ON; 4. print the word; 5. switch underline OFF; 6. print the rest. If you have any code so far, please include it in your question (use the Edit button).

Comment: .. note that the code in your previous question does not print *anything* of the source text. It may be a good start to add that first.

Comment: oh!yes...i made some changes i will upload the code later i had forget these changes

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will generally work:

```
printf("Normal \x1b[4mUnderlined\x1b[24m Normal.\n");
```