# C how to change a word's color

Tags: c, colors, console

I have a program in C that prints some info in a console application and I want to print some of the info in other color. Is this possible?

Edit:
my os is windows

Comment: What OS are you targeting? - See maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: i need it for windows

Comment: Well, you didn't say that in the question. Here's another duplicate that includes Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3274824/10077

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21590640/971127

Answer (score 1):

This is a little C program that can help you :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define KNRM  "\x1B[0m"
#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT  "\x1B[37m"

int main()
{
    printf("%sred\n", KRED);
    printf("%sgreen\n", KGRN);
    printf("%syellow\n", KYEL);
    printf("%sblue\n", KBLU);
    printf("%smagenta\n", KMAG);
    printf("%scyan\n", KCYN);
    printf("%swhite\n", KWHT);
    printf("%snormal\n", KNRM);

    return 0;
}
```

This article could Help : http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8603