# change input text color in c langage

Tags: c, windows, colors, command-prompt, scanf

I want to change the color of the input text with c
i was using :

```
textcolor(15);
cscanf("%d",d);
```

But when i execute and start typing there are a problem when i press backspace button to delete what i just typed

if i used just the `scanf` it will look like this:

[image]

Also i can't use the function `system("COLOR 6C");` because it change the color of all text

All i want is if there are any other way to color the input text

I'm using code::blocks (windows)

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: This has no general solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21590640/971127

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Answer (score 0):

Make another program and write this code -

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<298;i++)
  { 
     textcolor(i);
     printf("color in %d textcolor",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So you will see all colors effect that you can bring using textcolor.
In your case , background is blue and you want to take input in white color. so use `textcolor(159);scanf("%d",&d);` (blue background white font color).